# How does a php program emit an svg image?

Tags: php, image, svg

I'm trying the use of the "call a php program in an img href= tag" trick in order to dynamically create an image. Now, there are plenty of examples where the image generated is a raster image like a png. Something like:

```
 
   $img = imagecreate(500, 300);
   $bgcolor = imagecolorallocate($img, 150, 200, 180);
```

etc., etc, then ending with

```
    imagepng($image);
    imagedestroy($image);

?>
```

But I'm trying to figure out how to do this with an SVG image, whuch is a vector type. I thought of trying to test this by putting the following immediately before an SVG file such that

```
header("Content-Type: image/svg+xml");
?>
```

is immediately followed by the text of the SVG image. I know that for an actual output, print statements would be used, but I am trying to find out is something extra, or special, is needed to generate an SVG image in this context instead of a PNG.

Thank you for any help
Paul Robinson

Comment: You need to emit the `Content-Type: images/svg+xml` header, followed by the contents of the SVG file. Nothing more is needed. Have you tried doing that?

Comment: Have you tried it? Does it work? If not, what problem are you having?